# qconfig.cpp missing in qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.8.0

Tags: qt, compilation, open-source, qt5.8

I've just been downloading qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.8.0.zip from the Qt Website. As I tried to compile the qttools the compile process is missing the file qconfig.cpp.

I've searched for in the whole Archiv, but there is neighter a file "qconfig.cpp" in

- qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.8.0.zip nor in
- qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.8.0.tar.gz

Where can I get the correct (corresponding to version 5.8.0 of Qt) file?

Why isn'nt it in the archiv?

Comment: I think that qconfig.cpp is made in the configure process. did you ./configure the qt?

Comment: You're not building Qt correctly, that's all. Follow the [build documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-building.html) and you should be set.